# Arguments passed to a function change in value after the function returns to the calling sub

Tags: excel, vba

The function below accepts a word and checks if the word is in a list of words that is maintained in a public variable array. The calling sub passes an element of a string array to this function

```
 Function IsNormalCap(Mywrds As String) As Boolean

 If Right(Mywrds, 1) = "." Then Mywrds = Left(Mywrds, Len(Mywrds) - 1)

 i = 0
 Do While i < UBound(CapsType) + 1
      If (Mywrds <> CapsType(i)) Then
           i = i + 1
      Else
           Exit Do
      End If
 Loop
 If i = UBound(CapsType) + 1 Then
      IsNormalCap = False
 Else
      IsNormalCap = True
 End If
 End Function
```

Relevant lines from calling sub code:

```
 Dim buff() As String
 ....
 If (Not (IsNormalCap(buff(i + 1)))) Then
 ....code.....
 End if
```

Question:

buff(i+1) seems to be passed as a ByRef as the value of buff(i+1) is changing after the function is called. The words that contain period at the end are coming back to the sub without the period at the end. Why does this happen? Need some clarity on this as there are several such functions where such arguments are passed and I dont seem to know when the value is passed ByRef when the intention was to pass it as ByVal (and vice versa). Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I have been clear enough.

Comment: I learnt that ByRef is the default. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527(v=vs.60).aspx                                            But then why has this not happened before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Function declarations, parameters that are not specified as `ByRef` or `ByVal`, are by default `ByRef`

Extract from VBA help

> ByVal Optional. Indicates that the argument is passed by value.
>   ByRef Optional. Indicates that the argument is passed by reference.ByRef is the default in Visual Basic.

So, if you always want `ByVal`, specify that

```
Function IsNormalCap(ByVal Mywrds As String) As Boolean
```

If, on the other hand, you sometimes want `ByRef` and other times `ByVal`, you can *override* `ByRef` in the function call by enclosing the parameter in `()`

Eg If function is defined as

```
Function IsNormalCap(ByRef Mywrds As String) As Boolean
```

or

```
Function IsNormalCap(Mywrds As String) As Boolean
```

then

```
If Not IsNormalCap((buff(i + 1))) Then
```

will pass `buff(i + 1)` by value

Note, I've removed some redundant `()` from your code to aid clarity.

Comment: Many Thanks Chris. In my limited VBA experience I never had to specify ByVal so far and everything has been hunky dory without making anything explicit. But probably this is the first time I made some changes to a parameter inside a function that I did not want to reflect in the main sub... and promptly made the mistake. Many thanks.